Invalid Hook Call (Use State)
I am building a weather app and getting the invalid hooks error. Here is my code:
Search.js
import { AsyncPaginate } from "react-select-async-paginate";
import { useState } from "react";

const Search = ({onSearchChange}) => {
    
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);
    
    const handleOnChange = (searchData) => {
        setSearch(searchData);
        onSearchChange(searchData);
    }
    return (
        <AsyncPaginate
        placeholder = "Search for city"
        debounceTimeout={600}
        value={search}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
    )
}
export default Search;

App.js
import Search from './components/search/search';

function App() {
  const handleOnSearchChange = (searchData) => {
    console.log(searchData);
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Search onSearchChange= {handleOnSearchChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


The error is

react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
and fix this problem. printWarning @ react.development.js:209 error @
react.development.js:183 resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621 useAsyncPaginate @
useAsyncPaginate.ts:34 WithAsyncPaginate @ withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074 beginWork
@ react-dom.development.js:21587 beginWork$1 @
react-dom.development.js:27426 performUnitOfWork @
react-dom.development.js:26557 workLoopSync @
react-dom.development.js:26466 renderRootSync @
react-dom.development.js:26434 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25738 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 17 more frames Show less
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
and fix this problem. printWarning @ react.development.js:209 error @
react.development.js:183 resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621 useAsyncPaginate @
useAsyncPaginate.ts:34 WithAsyncPaginate @ withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074 beginWork
@ react-dom.development.js:21587 callCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4164 invokeGuardedCallbackDev @
react-dom.development.js:4213 invokeGuardedCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4277 beginWork$1 @
react-dom.development.js:27451 performUnitOfWork @
react-dom.development.js:26557 workLoopSync @
react-dom.development.js:26466 renderRootSync @
react-dom.development.js:26434 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25738 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 20 more frames Show less
react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties
of null (reading 'useState')
at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
at useAsyncPaginate (useAsyncPaginate.ts:34:1)
at WithAsyncPaginate (withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1) useState @ react.development.js:1622 useAsyncPaginate @ useAsyncPaginate.ts:34
WithAsyncPaginate @ withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53 renderWithHooks @
react-dom.development.js:16305 mountIndeterminateComponent @
react-dom.development.js:20074 beginWork @
react-dom.development.js:21587 callCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4164 invokeGuardedCallbackDev @
react-dom.development.js:4213 invokeGuardedCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4277 beginWork$1 @
react-dom.development.js:27451 performUnitOfWork @
react-dom.development.js:26557 workLoopSync @
react-dom.development.js:26466 renderRootSync @
react-dom.development.js:26434 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25738 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 17 more frames Show less
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
and fix this problem. printWarning @ react.development.js:209 error @
react.development.js:183 resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621 useAsyncPaginate @
useAsyncPaginate.ts:34 WithAsyncPaginate @ withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074 beginWork
@ react-dom.development.js:21587 beginWork$1 @
react-dom.development.js:27426 performUnitOfWork @
react-dom.development.js:26557 workLoopSync @
react-dom.development.js:26466 renderRootSync @
react-dom.development.js:26434 recoverFromConcurrentError @
react-dom.development.js:25850 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25750 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 18 more frames Show less
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
and fix this problem. printWarning @ react.development.js:209 error @
react.development.js:183 resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useState @ react.development.js:1621 useAsyncPaginate @
useAsyncPaginate.ts:34 WithAsyncPaginate @ withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074 beginWork
@ react-dom.development.js:21587 callCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4164 invokeGuardedCallbackDev @
react-dom.development.js:4213 invokeGuardedCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4277 beginWork$1 @
react-dom.development.js:27451 performUnitOfWork @
react-dom.development.js:26557 workLoopSync @
react-dom.development.js:26466 renderRootSync @
react-dom.development.js:26434 recoverFromConcurrentError @
react-dom.development.js:25850 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25750 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 21 more frames Show less
react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties
of null (reading 'useState')
at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
at useAsyncPaginate (useAsyncPaginate.ts:34:1)
at WithAsyncPaginate (withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1) useState @ react.development.js:1622 useAsyncPaginate @ useAsyncPaginate.ts:34
WithAsyncPaginate @ withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53 renderWithHooks @
react-dom.development.js:16305 mountIndeterminateComponent @
react-dom.development.js:20074 beginWork @
react-dom.development.js:21587 callCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4164 invokeGuardedCallbackDev @
react-dom.development.js:4213 invokeGuardedCallback @
react-dom.development.js:4277 beginWork$1 @
react-dom.development.js:27451 performUnitOfWork @
react-dom.development.js:26557 workLoopSync @
react-dom.development.js:26466 renderRootSync @
react-dom.development.js:26434 recoverFromConcurrentError @
react-dom.development.js:25850 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25750 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 18 more frames Show less
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the
 component:
at WithAsyncPaginate (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:63728:7)
at Search (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:104:3)
at div
at App


Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
learn more about error boundaries. logCapturedError @
react-dom.development.js:18687 update.callback @
react-dom.development.js:18720 callCallback @
react-dom.development.js:13923 commitUpdateQueue @
react-dom.development.js:13944 commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @
react-dom.development.js:23391 commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @
react-dom.development.js:24688 commitLayoutEffects_begin @
react-dom.development.js:24674 commitLayoutEffects @
react-dom.development.js:24612 commitRootImpl @
react-dom.development.js:26823 commitRoot @
react-dom.development.js:26682 finishConcurrentRender @
react-dom.development.js:25892 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25809 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 15 more frames Show less
react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties
of null (reading 'useState')
at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
at useAsyncPaginate (useAsyncPaginate.ts:34:1)
at WithAsyncPaginate (withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1) useState @ react.development.js:1622 useAsyncPaginate @ useAsyncPaginate.ts:34
WithAsyncPaginate @ withAsyncPaginate.tsx:53 renderWithHooks @
react-dom.development.js:16305 mountIndeterminateComponent @
react-dom.development.js:20074 beginWork @
react-dom.development.js:21587 beginWork$1 @
react-dom.development.js:27426 performUnitOfWork @
react-dom.development.js:26557 workLoopSync @
react-dom.development.js:26466 renderRootSync @
react-dom.development.js:26434 recoverFromConcurrentError @
react-dom.development.js:25850 performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @
react-dom.development.js:25750 workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239 performWorkUntilDeadline @
scheduler.development.js:533 Show 15 more frames Show less
content_getdify.js:1

I tried looking throughout stack overflow and couldn't find anything. I also tried deleting and reinstalling react.

The code you showed looks fine to me. Are you sure it's the useState in Search that's causing the problem? What's the full error and stack trace?

i edited it to add the error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') at useState (react.development.js:1622:1) at useAsyncPaginate (useAsyncPaginate.ts:34:1). Yep, something's wrong. Step 1 is to delete the node_modules folder and run npm install (or yarn if you're using yarn) again.

The culprit is useAsyncPaginate.
